# Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x264bd90) to 'NSString'

Tags: swift, error-handling, nsstring, nserror

So I'm getting a crash when I try to run this code and the error occurs. I can't figure out how to do it properly though.

Here is my func:

```
 @IBAction func MobilePay(_ sender: Any) {
        let payment = MobilePayPayment(orderId: "123456", productPrice: 10.0)
        //No need to start a payment if one or more parameters are missing
        if (payment != nil) && ((payment?.orderId.characters.count)! > 0) && ((payment?.productPrice)! >= 0) {
            MobilePayManager.sharedInstance().beginMobilePayment(with: payment!, error: { (Error) in
                print(Error)
                self.alert(message: Error as! String)
            })
        }
    }
```

and my errorLog:

Error Domain=com.danskebank.mobilepay Code=1001 "Not able to open the MobilePay app" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=MobilePay App is not installed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please install MobilePay app and try again., NSLocalizedDescription=Not able to open the MobilePay app}
Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x264bd90) to 'NSString' (0x264d6b8).
(lldb)

It seems the print works and the error is printed, but who do I get the last line

> Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x264bd90) to 'NSString'
>   (0x264d6b8). (lldb)

and how do I fix it?

Comment: Calling a local variable `Error` is obfuscating, since there is a *protocol* with the same name. Apart from that: What makes you think that you can cast an error to a string? `error.localizedDescription` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `localizedDescription` property of `Error` object, like this:

```
self.alert(message: Error.localizedDescription)
```

> Error Domain=com.danskebank.mobilepay Code=1001 "Not able to open the
>   MobilePay app" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=MobilePay App is not
>   installed, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Please install MobilePay app
>   and try again., **NSLocalizedDescription**=Not able to open the MobilePay
>   app} Could not cast value of type 'NSError' (0x264bd90) to 'NSString'
>   (0x264d6b8). (lldb)